# firebase rules for each user to write & read his own data

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework

tried looking for it on web but can't get this solution..
I got a firebase DB on my app and want to each user (auth) to be able to read and write only his own data.
got page in my app that generate the data that the user input but didn't get how to manage the rules so only the user itself could see and edit the data.

here are the rules:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

default ones!
what can I do?

Working with ionic framework

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
      ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
  }
}
```

As for example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "usersData": {
      "profiles": {
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
          ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in this example, the user can only write into his account under path `/usersData/profiles/[USER'S_AUTH_UID]/` with this the user can't read root path, can't see any profiles, and can't write to any node, except his own one.

---

**Edit**:
Also, there is a tool from firebase called [Bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt) this should be helpful making things easier and easier to maintain, also make advanced rules a lot simpler to implement, look at their [Guide here](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/docs/guide.md)

Comment: So I tried it and this went out:
ERROR Error: permission_denied at /Plans-list: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

Comment: @MatanCohen depends on your rules, maybe something wrong with it? see my edit tho.

Answer (score -1):

You should check this [Firebase - secure user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security)

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
  allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

In this case each user have own db. Just push some data to this ref /users/{userId}

Comment: Actually i need it on a list of items , not files.. so it's like a todo app